# Bean Validation 1.1 (JSR-349), implementation alternatives?

Tags: validation, javabeans, bean-validation

Besides the reference implementation, [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/) 5.x, are there alternative implementations of [JSR 349](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=349) (successor to JSR 303)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bean Validation 1.1 is not yet 100% finished (but it is close to be done), so other vendors are waiting for the final release.

You might watch

- https://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/ and
- http://bval.apache.org/

These are implementations of Bean Validation 1.0, but soon or later they would like to catch up with the final 1.1